# How limit android app to be installed only to tablet devices ( from 7 )

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet

I would like that my app will be installed only on tablet devices from play store.

How suggested from doc I sett this on my manifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I studied google doc and other post, for me this should works. 
It's strage that with this configuration play store doesn't limit any device, the app is available to any device.

**Is different from other similar ask because the answer doesn't work.**

Can someone help me?
thank in advance

Comment: the solution found in other similar post doesn't work for me